# How can I install mysql 5.0 on Ubuntu 10.04?

Tags: ubuntu-10.04, mysql

Is there any repo that will let me install mysql 5.0.51a on Ubuntu 10.04, or do I have to install it from scratch?

Sincerely
Tyler

Comment: Do you *really* need MySQL 5.0? Won't MySQL 5.1 work?

Answer (score 2):

Add this source to your sources.list:

```
deb http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu hardy-security main
```

do an `apt-get update` and then `aptitude search mysql-server-5.0` should return a result.

Comment: This worked for me after removing the file `/var/lib/mysql/debian-5.1.flag`

Answer (score 1):

One thing you can try is to install the .deb file from an older version's repository. It appears Hardy's repository has the .deb you are looking for. One issue with this method are dependencies that might pop up for libraries too old or, in this case probably, too new for the version of MySQL you want to use. Wouldn't hurt to try, though.

DEB Page: http://packages.ubuntu.com/hardy/misc/mysql-server-5.0